# SQL Server: Selecting 1 rows results in 1+3 rows affected?

Tags: sql-server, select, sql-server-2000, records

i'm selecting 1 row from a table:

```
select * from LCTs WHERE LCTGUID = 'B642B9E6-779A-4FD0-8514-294EAF87A9A6'

(1 row(s) affected)

(3 row(s) affected)
```

How can i get 4 rows affected by a single select (especially since it returns only one row)?

Bonus information:

- SQL Server 2000
- LCTs is a real table (i.e. not a view or UDF)
- there is no triggers on the table
- this is SQL Server 2000, which has no DDL auditing

Even more bizarre is that if i update that one row:

```
update LCTs SET IsDirty = 1 WHERE LCTGUID = 'B642B9E6-779A-4FD0-8514-294EAF87A9A6'

(1 row(s) affected)   

(5 row(s) affected)
```

How is an update of one row affecting 6 rows, in a table, without triggers, in SQL Server 2000?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This can happen if you have `Show Actual Execution Plan` turned on.  The second rowcount is for transferring the execution plan data.